# Chrome 61: Unexpected token import

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, es6-modules

Running Chrome 61 which is [supposed to support module loading](https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5365692190687232) with `import`.

Indeed Paul's [demo](https://paulirish.github.io/es-modules-todomvc/) works for me. However, when I try it myself I get a JS error "Unexpected token import". Chrome seems to balk at `import`:

test.html

```
<!doctype html> 
<html>
<body>
<script src="test.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

test.js:

```
import {hello} from './something.js'
console.log(hello())
```

something.js

```
export {hello}
function hello() {
    return "hello world"
}
```

Why does Chrome not understand "import"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For those of you who want to know exactly what worked for me, it was kind of a combination of a couple answers from above.  I also had to enable the ES6 import capabilities of Chrome by typing chrome://flags in the URL bar and searching for "import".

First the HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Testing JavaScript Stuff</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script type="module">
        import { circleArea, squareArea } from './CalcArea.js';

        console.log(circleArea(2));
        console.log(squareArea(2));
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

So as you can see just add the type "module" to your script tag, then below you do the import.  For my test the CalcArea.js file is this:

```
const circleArea = r => 3.14 * (r ** 2);

const squareArea = s => s * s;

export {circleArea, squareArea};
```

Comment: I agree, you need to enable the `import.meta.url` flag in Chrome *AND* add `type="module"` to your `<script>` tag.

Answer (score 20):

That should be `<script type=module src=test.js>`. The entire syntax is subtly changed in module scripts (`import` and `export` are allowed, as well as strict mode being mandatory).

Comment: The code works for me when using type=module. Nevertheless, Chrome developer tool still shows an error "Uncaught Syntax error: Unexpected token {" in test.js when editing the file. Any idea how to overcome that?

Comment: @Stefan Chrome v64 Developer Tools debugger still has a problem with import and export.

Answer (score 2):

Finally... figured it out.  `chrome://flags` search for `import` enable ES6 import syntax. Restart Chrome.  Be happy.

Comment: ...after going through and renaming all my `.js` files to `.mjs` because I thought the error went away after trying it, but apparently it was just processing.  Now I need to decide whether to name them all back or stick with `.mjs`