# "import" unexpected token? (chrome 62)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

While trying to troubleshoot why systemjs didn't find a custom library I installed (could be a follow up question) I was stuck when trying to do things "manually".

So I have a simple system that consists of 3 files:

- index.html
- hi.js
- hi2.js

the index is just:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Test</title>
</head>

<body>
<script src="hi.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

hi.js:

```
import * as hi from "hi2.js";

hi.myFunction();
```

hi2.js:

```
function myFunction() {
  alert('hi')
}
export { myFunction };
```

Now when I run (using webstorm and chrome 62) above code, I get the following error, reported by the (chrome) debugger: 
"Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token import"

What's happening here? I checked for javascript compliance [on mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import) and it tells me import is supported by chrome 61 and newer. - I use chrome 62 for testing this.

So what's going on, and how to make it work?

Per [recomendation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46306148/chrome-61-unexpected-token-import) I also changed the html line to `<script type="module" src="hi.js"></script>`. That didn't help at all, same error.

Comment: When you added `type="module"`, instead of the unexpected token error, you should have been getting `Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier 'hi2.js'`. (I did, on Chrome 62.)

Comment: Here is a plnkr with your files. I've verified this working in Chrome 61 after making the fix to add `./`.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: indeed, I didn't go deep enough, not running the "module" in debug mode on that and just saw it not work, thinking the error would've been the same; need to wait before accepting.

Comment: @paul23: I hate when I do that (and I do it more often than I'd like).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You're correct that you need `type="module"` on your script tag:

```
<script src="hi.js" type="module"></script>
<!-- ---------------^^^^^^^^^^^^^       -->
```

You also need a `./` prefix on your module specifier:

```
import * as hi from "./hi2.js";
// ------------------^^
```

This is to leave the door open for a specifier with no path at all to have special meaning at some stage as things evolve. From [the WHAT-WG spec](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#integration-with-the-javascript-module-system):

> This restriction *(that a relative URL specifier must start with `/`, `./`, or `../` – T.J.)* is in place so that in the future we can allow custom module loaders to give special meaning to "bare" import specifiers, like `import "jquery"` or `import "web/crypto"`. For now any such imports will fail, instead of being treated as relative URLs.

When I make those two changes to your files, with Chrome 62 with no experimental flags set, I get the alert.