# Export variable from an immediately invoked JavaScript function

Tags: javascript, angular, function

I am trying to export a variable from an immediately invoked JavaScript function. I need that variable to be imported in other components of my project. I am using Angular CLI for development. I have an external JS file from which I need to export this variable.
Below is the JS code sample of what I have so far:

```
var test;
!(function() { test = "123"; })();
export { test };
```

My project builds without errors but I get the following runtime error in the browser:

```
Google Chrome: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token export
Mozilla FireFox: SyntaxError: export declarations may only appear at top 
                 level of a module
Microsoft Edge: SCRIPT1002: SCRIPT1002: Syntax error
```

Appreciate your help.

Comment: The syntax is fine. If you're trying to use it directly in a browser, [you need `type="module"`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46306148/chrome-61-unexpected-token-import). If you're using a bundler to handle import/export, apparently this file isn't being handled -- you'll need to look at your bundler configuration.

Comment: Side note: That code is exactly the same as `export var test = 123;`. But if there's really a reason for using a function to create the value, don't make it a side effect, make it a *return value*: `export var test = (function() { /*...return theValue...*/ })();`

Answer (score -1):

First, why you are using a var? you need this variable global?
Second, ES provid export for both function and variable...

try this

```
export function test () {
    return test = "123";
}
```

Comment: Providing an explanation as to why/how this would solve the OPs question is helpful.