# Javascript import and export Unexpected token error

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

I want to import data to Javascript.js from Export.js. But im getting Unexpected token error.

Error : [image]

This is my Export.js file

```
export const expData = [1,2,3];
```

This is my Javascript.js file

```
import { expData } from './Export.js';
console.log(expData);
```

There is no html code on it, I just run it on Terminal.
Please help me if you guys have any solutions. Thanks.

Comment: What's the error message it shows?

Comment: A couple of things to try. Depending on the environment (node or browser), it may not understand ES6 code.  If you try plain old `require` and it works, then you know it is an issue with the environment understanding ES6 code.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46306148/chrome-61-unexpected-token-import

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41722621/es6-in-the-browser-uncaught-syntaxerror-unexpected-token-import

Comment: @snewcomer I didn't run it on Chrome or Firefox. I only run it on Visual Studio code Terminal.

Comment: @MuraliNepalli question updated lol

Comment: I suspect your setup does not support ES2015 or greater. Do you have reason to think that such features would be supported? What happens when you comment out the `import` and use other modern features, like your `const expData` declaration?

Comment: @JakeWorth you mean declare const expData and Console.Log(expData) on the same .js file ? If is that then it work fine actually, just that import export have error.

Comment: @Kai thanks for looking into that. I still think the issue here is lack of ES2015/6+ support.